# how to implement basic authentication in mvc4 web api?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

what steps need to be implemented in order to have basic authentication for asp.net mvc4 web api?

I need to verify username and password received in header with database records?

Comment: Please show what you have already tried/implemented.

Comment: Use GoogleFu: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication